# Unity, WaitUntil in a self-made message box class

Tags: unity-game-engine

I managed to make a simple message box prefab with a `Text` and a `Button` through `Canvas`, and then instantiate it through the constructor.

```
public class MessageBox
{
    public MessageBox(string msg)
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load(@"MsgBox"));

        obj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = msg;
    }
}
```

So when another script needed it, simply do

```
MessageBox mb = new MessageBox("This is a test message!");
```

This all worked fine, but then I wish to change it to like normal MessageBox where the code was suspended, but not locked, until the user click the OK or Cancel button.

I managed to do it by calling a coroutine **`in the calling script`**.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("Do");
}

IEnumerator Do()
{
    MessageBox mb = new MessageBox("This is also a test message!");

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => GlobalVariables.MsgBoxClicked == true);
    //GlobalVariables is a separate class containing some static variables.
    Debug.Log("Done!");
}
```

(You have to set the `MsgBoxClicked` to `false` when the prefab is created and set it to `true` when the button is clicked, of course.)

But that means every time I needed to use the message box, I need to call a coroutine!

And that's super inefficient no matter how you looked at it!

So I tried to move the coroutine into the `MessageBox` class itself.

But now here comes the problem!

The `MessageBox` does NOT inherit from `MonoBehaviour`!

And you can't call a coroutine without it!

I had tried to make the `MessageBox` inherited from `MonoBehaviour`, but the Unity warned me **`This is not allowed`** every time I tried to new it! Even though the game ran smoothly.

I even tried to new the `MonoBehaviour` itself and call its `StartCouroutine`, but of course, the same warning popped up! And this time the game won't even run!

I also tried to use the old `AutoResetEvent`, but it locked the whole thing and crashed my game!

So, could somebody be so kind and teach me how to get around it!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just have an event of "onclicked" and work from there

Comment: @BugFinder Can you elaborate it a little more please!?

Comment: Well create an event so that "onclicked" it can be responded to by anything that subscribed to that event

Comment: @BugFinder OK, let me go ponder through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments just make it event driven.

I would even go a little further and you could directly tell the `MessageBox` what to do when is "done" like

```c#
public enum MessageBoxResponse
{
    Confirmed,
    Declined,
    Canceled
}

public class MessageBox
{

    // You can give the Action any parameter you like e.g.
    public Action<MessageBoxResponse> done;

    // Additional flag inncase you still want to use it in routines
    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    public MessageBox(string msg, Action<MessageBoxResponse> onDone)
    {
        IsDone = false;

        var obj = (GameObject)MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load(@"MsgBox"));

        obj.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true).text = msg;

        // Now this will simply tell the Button to call SetDone
        // (As this is added on runtime it won't appear in the Inspector)
        obj.GetComponentInChildren<Button>(true).onClick.AddListener(Confirm);

        done += onDone;
    }

    private void Confirm()
    {
        SetDone(MessageBoxResponse.Confirmed);
    }

    private void SetDone(MessageBoxResponse response)
    {
        if(IsDone) return;

        IsDone = true;

        done?.Invoke(response);
    }
}
```

Then when creating the box you can directly pass in the callback either as lambda expression

```c#
var msgBox = new MessageBox("example", response => 
    {
        Debug.Log("Done with response " + response);
    }
);
```

Or the same as method call

```c#
var msgBox = new MessageBox("example", OnMessageDone);

private void OnMessageDone(MessageBoxResponse response)
{
    Debug.Log("Done with response" + response);
}
```

And you can also add callbacks afterwards using

```c#
msgBox.done += OnMessageDone;
// Or lambda
msgBox.done += response => { Debug.Log("Done with response " + response); };
```

When the button is clicked the `MessageBox` itself will automatically call `SetDone` and invoke all listeners without the need for any routine waiting for it.

In case you still want to use it also to stall a routine anyway you can use the

```c#
yield return new WaitUntil (() => msgBox.IsDone);
```

Comment: I tested your code out, it works great! Thanks! But the code didn't "suspend" (Or is there other proper way to say it!?). Namely, the codes after the `new MessageBox(...)` didn't wait until I click the button! Could you please be so kind and teach me how to do it!? Much appreciated!

Comment: It won't because it doesn't use a Coroutine anymore .. it is as said event driven. I you want some code to wait until the message is closed then move it into the `onDone` callback.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean. But my thinking is, make it like the MessageBox in VS where you could put it in an if statement and check which button had been clicked. Anything behind it have to wait! Could you please be so kind and point me to the right direction!? Much appreciated!

Comment: I extended the answer a bit. Basically you can pass in whatever parameter(s) you like to the `Action` callback. Listener methods simply have to implement the according signature. Ofcourse you'll have to set the listener for each of your buttons accordingly. Here I would suggest to use proper classes like `ConfirmButton`, `CancelButton` etc so you can simply find the using `GetComponentInChildren`

Comment: Thanks! Let me go test it out!

Comment: I got it! All I have to do is to run **EVERYTHING** in the coroutine! And call `WaitUntil` every time I wish it to wait! And put the if statement afterwards! It's kind of extra works, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: As said if that is all you wait for in the routine I wouldn't use it at all but rather normal methods and just place the delayed code block into the callback of the MessageBox but ofcourse it's up to you how you want to use it ;)

Comment: I know what you mean. But what I'm trying to do is to make it like the `MessageBox.Show` does. Where you could put it in the `if` conditions and execute the statement block inside it **after** the user click the button. But my programming skill is nowhere near that yet! So all I can do is cheat the system! :)

Comment: well, but that's basically exactly what my `MessageBox` does .. just without an `if`. Instead you do whatever you would do in the `if` and after that within the callback ;)

Comment: I don't seems to know how to make it work! But I'll go pull my hair off over it! Thanks! XP

Answer (score 1):

> But that means every time I needed to use the message box, I need to call a coroutine!

I don't think this is a problem. As the quote goes [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil). So is it really that computationally expensive for your application?

However, there are a number of ways to call a coroutine method from another class. Basically, it all comes down to having a *context* reference, i.e. reference to any `MonoBehaviour` instance.

```
public static void InvokeCoroutine(MonoBehaviour context, IEnumerator coroutine)
{
    context.StartCoroutine(coroutine);
}
```